# Error event.total = 0

Tags: javascript, php

Necesito poder mostrar en la `progressbar` el tiempo que tarda un archivo en cargarse al formulario.

Esto es lo que tengo ahora:

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('El tiempo que tarde desde aqui...');
  var url = './upload.php';
  var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
  var txt = "";

  if ('files' in x) {
    if (x.files.length == 0) {
      txt = "Select one or more files.";
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {

        txt += "<br><strong>" + (i + 1) + ". file</strong><br>";
        let file = x.files[i];
        if ('name' in file) {
          txt += "name: " + file.name + "<br>";
        }
        if ('size' in file) {
          txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes";
        }

        /*******************************************************************************/
        /*********************************REQUEST***************************************/
        /*******************************************************************************/

        let peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();

        peticion.addEventListener("progress", (event) => {

        /***********************************/
        /*************PROBLEMA**************/
        /***********************************/
        console.log(event);
        console.log(event.loaded);
        console.log(event.total);
        /***********************************/
        /*************PROBLEMA**************/
        /***********************************/


          let porcentaje = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);

          document.getElementsByTagName('progress')[0].value = porcentaje;
          txt += "loading: " + porcentaje + "%<br>";
        });

        // Crear objeto FormData
        let data = new FormData();

        // Agregar archivo
        data.append('file', file);

        // Inicializar petición
        peticion.open('POST', url);

        // Escuchar cambios de estado
        peticion.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (peticion.readyState == 4) {
            // Se completó la petición, hay que analizar el resultado
            if (peticion.status == 200) {
              // El archivo se subió correctamente
              // Obtener respuesta del servidor
              let resp = peticion.responseText;
              //console.log(resp);
              console.log('...Hasta aqui');
              //document.getElementById('btn-progressbar').click();
            } else {
              console.log('...Hasta aqui');
              console.log('A partir de aqui se mandaría otra petición que no viene al caso, por ello la url a un php a parte');
            }
          }
        };
        // Ejecutar petición, enviando archivo
        peticion.send(data);

        /*******************************************************************************/
        /*********************************REQUEST***************************************/
        /*******************************************************************************/
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (x.value == "") {
      txt += "Select one or more files.";
    } else {
      txt += "The files property is not supported by your browser!";
      txt += "<br>The path of the selected file: " + x.value;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" name="subir_archivo" onchange="myFunction()">
    <input type="submit" id="btn-progressbar" value="Upload" style="visibility:hidden">
  </form>
  <br>
  <progress value="0" max="100"></progress>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Al hacer un console.log

Comment: No logro entender tu código. Por ejemplo, ¿qué hace un `header location` en el archivo PHP que debería procesar el contenido que estarías enviando desde el cliente vía Ajax? Y, ¿por qué usas variables de sesión? ¿Sabes cómo funciona Ajax? Desde PHP tú debes emitir un mensaje (no una redirección) cuando el archivo sea procesado o si hay error, etc. y verificar ese mensaje en el estatus 200 de la petición Ajax (en Javascript). Para ayudarte con esto, explícanos lo que entiendes de Ajax brevemente y dinos por qué usas redirecciones y variables de sesión. Verifica también la consola.

Comment: Si no pongo el header.location en el archivo PHP, cuando consigo mandar el archivo a su carpeta correctamente, me deja en la página en blanco, porque upload.php no tiene nada de contenido. Sin embargo si se lo pongo, una vez haya resuelto la petición, me devuelve a la página donde quiero estar.
Las variables de sesión me permiten poder ver los mensajes de upload.php en la página principal, gracias al location.header. Y he llegado a llenar de console.logs el archivo para ver si todo funciona. PERO, cuando mando el archivo, en la página principal, no consigo que se muestre la barra de progreso.

Comment: Pero el problema es esencialmente eso. Mediante JS no logro hacer que la progressbar aumente en proporción al archivo cargándose en el formulario. Es decir, si cargo un archivo al formulario, y tiene 100Mb, quiero que me muestre el % desde el 0 hasta que carguen los 100Mb del archivo. Pero mediante Js, claro...
Y como el event.total es 0 siempre, no logro hacer la operación matemática de marras...

Comment: **Ajax no funciona de ese modo**. Mientras no entiendas cómo funciona Ajax dudo que puedas resolver el problema adecuadamente. Cuando usas Ajax no necesitas ni redirecciones ni variables de sesión para obtener los mensajes que ocurran durante el procesamiento de la petición. Para explicarlo de modo sencillo: Ajax te permite una comunicación entre cliente (Javascript) y servidor (PHP). Y en esa comunicación puedes enviar/recibir cosas de un lado y de otro sin necesidad de otros intermediarios. Creo que ese es el problema principal: no entiendes cómo funciona Ajax.

Comment: Pero es que no necesito información del lado del servidor :(

Solamente necesito mostrar el proceso de carga, mediante la progressbar, del archivo subiendose al formulario, no a un servidor. no se si me explico

Comment: Según lo dicho en un comentario anterior: *Las variables de sesión me permiten poder ver los mensajes de upload.php en la página principal, gracias al location.header.* Parece que sí necesitas obtener información del lado del servidor. Además, el mismo archivo que mandas desde el formulario lo mandas al servidor. Repito de nuevo que aquí el problema es que no entiendes cómo funciona Ajax. Si no tienes claro el contexto en el que estás trabajando ni cómo funcionan las herramientas que estás usando, no podrás resolver este problema de ningún modo, o a lo sumo de una forma bastante precaria.

Comment: Vale, vuelvo a repetir, en un formulario simple y llanamete, donde no hubiera php de por medio, querría mostrar el tiempo que tarda en cargar el archivo al formulario. Ahora edito completamente la pregunta para ello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado:

```html
<?php
session_start(); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
function _(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile() {
  var file = _("file1").files[0];
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("file1", file);
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
  ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
  ajax.open("POST", "upload.php");
  ajax.send(formdata);
}

function progressHandler(event) {
  _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
  var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
  _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
}

function completeHandler(event) {
  console.log('completado');
  _('btn-progressbar').click();
}

function errorHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}

function abortHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>

<body>

<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['message']) && $_SESSION['message'])
    {
      printf('<b>%s</b>', $_SESSION['message']);
      unset($_SESSION['message']);
    }
  ?>

  <h2>HTML5 File Upload Progress Bar Tutorial</h2>
  <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="uploadFile()"><br>
    <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
    <h3 id="status"></h3>
    <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
    <input type="submit" id="btn-progressbar" value="Upload" style="visibility:hidden">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```